# Creating DIVs from XML content with Css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Before I start I should note that I found a similar post at
[dynamically creating HTML divs with JS from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639060/dynamically-creating-html-divs-with-js-from-xml)

But it is missing some key elements such as
The 'GET' method to get the file mentioned.Plus I want to try to achieve this completely with JavaScript. so here it goes:

I want my javascript to load content from an XML document. I've worked with editing JavaScript and other coding languages many time but nothing to this extent. So my XML form is this :

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?><messages>
     <message>
<image>note1.jpg</image>
        <text>Hello, This is the first message.</text>
<note>Notes for the first message</note>
      </message>
    <message>
<image>note2.png</image>
        <text>Now,this is a second message</text>
<note>Notes for the second message</note>
      </message>
    </messages>
```

My JavaScript is:

```
let page = 1;
const last_page = 10;
const pixel_offset = 200;
const throttle = (callBack, delay) => {
  let withinInterval;
  return function () {
    const args = arguments;
    const context = this;
    if (!withinInterval) {
      callBack.call(context, args);
      withinInterval = true;
      setTimeout(() => withinInterval = false, delay);
    }
  };
};

const httpRequestWrapper = (method, URL) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr_obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr_obj.responseType = "json";
    xhr_obj.open(method, URL);
    xhr_obj.onload = () => {
      const data = xhr_obj.response;
      resolve(data);
    };
    xhr_obj.onerror = () => {
      reject("failed");
    };
    xhr_obj.send();
  });
};

const getData = async (page_no = 1) => {
  const data = await httpRequestWrapper(
  "GET",
  `myXML.xml`);


  const { results } = data;
  populateUI(results);
};

let handleLoad;

let trottleHandler = () => {throttle(handleLoad.call(this), 1000);};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  getData(1);
  window.addEventListener("scroll", trottleHandler);
});

handleLoad = () => {
  if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight - pixel_offset) {
    page = page + 1;
    if (page <= last_page) {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', trottleHandler);
      getData(page).
      then(res => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', trottleHandler);
      });
    }
  }
};







const populateUI = data => {
  const container = document.querySelector('.whole_wrapper');
  data &&
  data.length &&
  data.
  map((each, index) => {
    const {  photoVar } = image;
    const { textVar } = text;
    const { noteVar } = note;
    container.innerHTML +=
    `
    <div class="each_bubble">
      <div class="imageContainer">
        <img src="${photoVar}" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="right_contents_container">
        <div class="text_field">${textVar}</div>
        <div class="note_field">${noteVar}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    `;
  });

};
```

My HTML simply loads the JavaScript and CSS into the page.

Each DIV should have its own photo, text and note. I'm pretty sure I can do the CSS part once I can get this to completely load.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out already. The content that this code was preliminarily made for is JSON instead of XML. I have decided to use JSON given it's ease of access and use on server side platforms.

I was just nervous to use something new and was trying to use XML since I have had experience with XML. So lesson to be learned here "when the opportunity comes to try something new for a project, try it" Especially when you see the outcome in the code but not sure of the method"
Thanks to those who has considered replying to his.